Define coordinate for multiple tikzpicture
I have multiple similar tikzpicture (used with beamer overlays).
Is it possible have a single coordinate definition that would be usable within each tikzpicture ?
This would avoid duplication in the MWE below
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node[draw] at (a) {A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0); % duplicated line
    \node[draw] at (a) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

(Of course my real usage is much more complex, using beamer slides with tikzpictures dozen of frames appart...)

You could write in your preamble e.g. \newcommand\crd[0]{\coordinate (a) at (0,0);} and inside tikzpicture \crd{} . Or define just the coordinate itself as a constant, like \coordinate at \cval{}; where it now contains (0,0) . Whatever is best for you.

(a) is stored globally relative to the origin, but each tikzpicture has a separate origin.  [remember picture] would store the relative positions of the origins and correct (assuming one definition).  You would also need [overlay] if the two tikzpictures overlap or they will keep moving around.

If you'd directly place your tikz pictures in your beamer presentation, you can use a single tikzpicture and avoid any repetition:
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}<1>[label=foo]
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (a) at (0,0);
    \node<1>[draw] at (a) {A};
    \node<2>[draw] at (a) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
dozen of frames
\end{frame}

\againframe<2>{foo}

\end{document}


<3 awesome ! I've been looking for this and gave up any hope.

@Jav You're welcome!

You can do this even if you don't put the picture directly into the presentation. The slide specification will still work if the picture is \input, say, with standalone.

@cfr I was considering this, but switching to beamer seemed easier. If I'm not mistaken, I would have needed the beamer option to use overlays in standalone. I would then have to re-enable cropping etc....

All I meant was: you don't have to have the code in the same file. I don't like having long picture code in my main file, so I typically would put the tikzpicture in another file and just \input it in the main one. All I meant was there's no reason you can't have the code for the picture be separate. standalone is just nice because I can work on the picture separately. You would either need the beamer or something like I have, yes. (I basically have a standard configuration for mapping overlay stuff to nothing outside beamer.) I'm not sure about cropping because my method avoids that.

I guess it works for me because I don't tend to write \node<2> but \node [only=<2>] or whatever and then it is easy to fake it outside beamer. But that is definitely more complicated to set up than your answer.

@cfr Ah! Personally, I like subfiles in such situations. This allows me to work on parts of the document separately, but I still have all the goodies from the class/packages available.

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I like standalone for precisely the same reason. It avoids loading the overhead of my main document's preamble. ;)

@cfr If we'll find ourself ever in a situation of a shortage of tex distributions, we can share one: you can get standalone and I'll get subfiles :)

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Deal ;).
